# Why do Cordova cookies work inconsistently across installs?

Tags: cordova, cookies

My Cordova app uses cookie-based authentication. Some of my users get logged out unexpectedly, other users have been using the same session for months. For those for whom it works, it works consistently, and vice versa. This occurs on both iOS and Android. Some installs on a given OS version keep the cookie for a while, and some on the same OS version don't. And nobody's going in to the app settings and clearing the data.

I've searched for a reason for this, and have found lots of "You shouldn't use cookies, use local storage instead" responses. See:

[Cookie based Authentication on Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463188/cookie-based-authentication-on-phonegap)

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/sessions-or-cookies-angularjs-phonegap/613

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/authentication_session_cookies_in_android

The last link even hints at there being no intentional support for cookies in Cordova.

Fine! I'll switch to something else... but does anyone know *why* cookies are so unreliable in Cordova. They clearly work. And even in those cases where people get logged out, they're still using cookies effectively for a short time, b/c the initial auth call is AJAX and AJAX API calls do work with the cookie returned by the initial AJAX auth call.

So why the inconsistency? Any ideas?

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100874/why-does-an-html5-app-work-differently-in-the-browser-than-it-does-in-cordova-a It is the exact same reason.

Comment: TL;DR - Cordova does not handle cookies as cookies are part of the frontend layer of the application. The native webview handles the cookies and that support varies between platform/SDK version.

Comment: Thanks, that's enlightening. So it sounds like someone at Apple may have decided that they didn't like how UIWebView in iOS 7.1.1 kept cookies forever (or till they expired), and in 7.1.2 changed it to destroy cookies after an arbitrary amount of time, say a few hours. But then changed their mind again and now they stay around forever in iOS 8.1.2. That's just great!

Comment: To make things even more confusing, Apple has added a second webview type in iOS8. The new one is supposed to be more friendly with HTML5 and JS, but currently does not work with Cordova because it does not allow loading local files. Huge oversight, but they are working on fixing it.